# Call to a member function get() on a non-object in lib/saemc.class.php on line 31

Tags: php

## test.php

```
<?php
$cache = new cache();
echo $cache->getcache('test.php');
?>
```

---

## cache.class.php file

```
<?php
class cache extends saemc{
    var $db;

    function cache(){
    $this->db=$db;
}
    function getcache($cachename){
    return $this->getvalue($cachename);
}
?>
```

---

## saemc.class.php file

```
<?php
class saemc {
    static $handler;

    protected function getvalue($filename) {
     $content = $this->handler->get($filename);//this  incorrect line
    ......
   }
?>
```

why $handler use "static" modifier , but $this->handler is still non-object ?

Comment: Where is `$handler` initialized?

Comment: static variables are not accessible via `$this` context, rather via `self::$varName`.